# When to compile and deploy content

Tags: setup-di-compile, magento2.2.7

After a year or so of working in `Developer Mode`, I'm now using `Production Mode`.

As I deploy updates to modules or designs, I'm wondering when I should run the below commands. At the moment, my order of operations is:

1. Update files in `app/code` or `app/design`
2. Run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`
3. Run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB`

Is this still necessary when updating something like a **stylesheet** or **template**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade` :

> Upgrades the Magento application, DB data, and schema

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile` :

> Generates DI configuration and all missing classes that can be
>   auto-generated

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` :

> Deploys static view files

**CSS** where is it placed ? in **view** files : `app/design/frontend/{Theme}/{name}/web/css/custom.css` or `app/code/Vendor/Name/view/frontend/web/css/custom.css` So YES you need to deploy the `static-contents` on **production** mode.

Magento [DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html) says :

> The static view files deployment command enables you to write static
>   files to the Magento file system when the Magento software is set for
>   production mode.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

The brief answer is yes for stylesheet/templates you would then need to redeploy the static content. You wouldn't need to compile.

Compilation would be required for something like, for example, adding a new extension or adding a new instance of a model into an existing module.